# Regular expression to match any number unless it's followed by a given character

Tags: regex

I'm stuck on creating a reg ex that matches and groups any number of digits **unless** it's followed directly by a letter `A`

What I want:

```
1     -> 1
1B    -> 1
11B   -> 11
1A    -> nothing
11A   -> nothing
```

In the reg ex I have (https://regex101.com/r/jdlDe9/1), I use a negative look-ahead: `.*(\d+)(?!A)`. It works if a single digit is followed by an `A` but still matches if multiple digits are followed by an `A`

```
1     -> 1        OK
1B    -> 1        OK
12B   -> 12       OK
1A    -> nothing  OK
12A   -> 1        NOT OK. Here it matches the first `1` but I don't want to match anything
```

Comment: Depending on the regex engine, you can make the quantifier for the digits possessive and match only the digits `\d++(?!A)` or capture the digits `(\d+)(?:[^A\d]|$)` and match not A or digits or assert end of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantifiers in the pattern `.*(\d+)(?!A)` allow backtracking, so the the \d+ that matches `12` in `12A` can backtrack one position and have the lookahead evaluate to true.

You can match capture 1+ digits, followed by matching any char except A or a digit, or assert the end of the string

```
(\d+)(?:[^A\d]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7tf3oD/1)

Or if [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) are supported, that not allow backtracking after there is a match, and you can get a match only without the capture group:

```
\d++(?!A)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DkPMrk/1)